# table rows are printing in a php loop and i want to enter in table row cell from java script, if i print in console it giving correct output

Tags: javascript, php, html, console

```
`while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {`
      `$food=$row["order_name"];`
      `$price=$row["order_price"];`
      `$quantity=$row["order_quantity"];`
      `echo '<form action="/wowfood/cart.php" method="post">`
          `<tr>`
           `<th scope="row">'.$sno.'</th>`
           `<td>'.$food.'<input type="hidden" name="order_name" value="'.$food.'"</td>`
           `<td> <input type="number" class="iquantity" onchange="subtotal()" value="'.$quantity.'" min=1 style="hight: 25px;width: 45px;display: block;border: 1px solid black;border-radius: 6px;"> </td>`
           `<td>'.$price.'<input type="hidden" class="iprice" value="'.$price.'"</td>`
           `<td id="itotal"></td>`
           `<td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Remove</button></td>`
          `</tr>`
           ` </form>';`
           `$sno=$sno+1;`
         '}'
                                    

       `<script type="text/javascript">`
           `var iprice= document.getElementsByClassName("iprice");`
           `var iquantity=document.getElementsByClassName("iquantity");`
           `var itotal=document.getElementById("itotal");`
           `function subtotal(){`
           `for (i = 0; i<iprice.length; i++) {`
              `itotal[i]= (iprice[i].value)*(iquantity[i].value);`
               `console.log(itotal[i]);`                             
           ` }`
       ` }`
        `subtotal();`
 
    `</script>`
```

i am trying to print the value of th tag with id itotal itotal depends on iqauntity and iprice if i console print the value it is giving the correct values but i am failed to put that value in html.
i total eitehr giving an html list or on console it giving correct values.
basically i have a table in which i wan to change the subtotal on the basis of quantity.
thanks in advance

Comment: You mean you want to put the total into the itotal cell? What have you tried? You say you are failing but I see no attempt here. It should be a simple matter of setting the innerHTML of that element

Comment: Why those backticks? Please remove them. Main issue: you did it correctly with the two classes, then suddenly use an `id` for the total. It's `getElementById`, i.e. a single element, which is what an `id` is supposed to be: a unique element. Use a class instead, like with the other two: https://jsfiddle.net/8s75cbwm/

Comment: @ChrisG yeahh got it thanks for help and i am using stackoverflow for the first time so those backticks it says use them for a new line so

Comment: `those backticks it says use them for a new line`....where does it say that? I think maybe you misunderstood something. They are not necessary for making a new line. As you can see, they simply appear in the output instead

Comment: To post code, either indent everything by 4 spaces (you can select the code and press Ctrl+K to do that) or put three backticks before the first and after the last line.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting